# AWS Cognito built-in sign in redirection issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-cognito

I am trying to incorporate Cognito built-in sign in logic into our workflow.
Here is scenario I try put to work:
I need redirect to specific URI after successful signing in through Cognito built-in UI of the user, which has been created in the User Pool. But I do not understand how to do it.
I've created  User Pool, app client, configured domain, provided callback url, created a user.

I configured "Allowed OAuth Flows" to use`Authorization code grant` "Allowed OAuth Scopes" is set to `openid`
So far - so good.
Then I came up following URL to conjure up Cognito built-in UI:

```
https://<my-domain>.amazoncognito.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<my-client-id>&redirect_uri=https://<my-domain>.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=<my-client-id>
```

Upon executing it in a browser of my choice I am hitting Cognito built-in sign in page. But upon clicking "Sign in" button I've got an error: `Required String parameter 'redirect_uri' is not present`

Ok, I thought to myself, let's add redirect_uri attribute at the end of the aforementioned URL and path would be cleared to success, but such optimism has been short lived. I've got dreaded: "redirect_mismatch" error. I've tried to provide multiple callback urls, but with no success. redirect_mismatch error blocking my way.

And now I have no idea how to instruct Cognito to redirect to desired url. Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't set the 'redirect_uri' to Cognito's Login Endpoint. It makes no sense. The 'redirect_uri' is a parameter to tell Cognito where to take the user after login, which would be your application's url.

The 'redirect_uri' **should exactly match** one of the Callback URIs for the app client you configured for security reasons, otherwise you will get a' redirect_mismatch' error.

To access the login endpoint:

```
https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
```

For the authorize endpoint:

```
https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
```

The authorize endpoint firsts checks to see if you have a session cookie indicating that you're already logged in, and if you are, it automatically redirects you to the redirect_uri, otherwise it will take you to the login page via the Login Endpoint with the query strings provided to the authorize endpoint.